# Superimpose a normal distribution to a density using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to superimpose a normal distribution to a density using ggplot in R:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=Rel, y=..density..)) +
    geom_density(aes(fill=factor(cut)), position="stack") +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = Rel.mean, sd = Rel.sd))
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'density' not found
Calls: print ... <Anonymous> -> as.data.frame -> lapply -> FUN -> eval
```

Why? Any solution?

Comment: You will get an answer easier if you provide a small [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: See the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688082/ggplot2-overlay-histogram-with-density-curve).  The error is likely because you set a global y instead of setting y in `geom_density`.

Comment: without data and a MWE, this question is not useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @aosmith advice:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=Rel)) +
    geom_density(aes(y=..density.., fill=factor(cut)), position="stack") +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = Rel.mean, sd = Rel.sd))
```

Works!

Comment: without data and a MWE, this answer is not useful. Please provide something along the lines of  ``ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl))) + geom_density(aes(y = ..density.., fill = factor(gear)), position = "stack") + stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd))``

Comment: and a screenshot of the plot would be even better.