# Plotting normal curve over histogram using ggplot2: Code produces straight line at 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

this forum already helped me a lot for producing the code, which I expected to return a histogram of a specific variable overlayed with its empirical normal curve. I used ggplot2 and stat_function to write the code.
Unfortunately, the code produced a plot with the correct histogram but the normal curve is a straight line at zero (red line in plot produced by the following code).

For this minimal example I used the mtcars dataset - the same behavior of ggplot and stat_function is observed with my original data set.

This is the code is wrote and used:

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars
hist_staff <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mtcars$mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 2, colour = "black", aes(fill = ..count..)) +
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "#DCDCDC", high = "#7C7C7C") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = "red")
print(hist_staff)
```

I also tried to specify dnorm:

```
stat_function(fun = dnorm(mtcars$mpg, mean = mean(mtcars$mpg), sd = sd(mtcars$mpg))
```

That did not work out either - an error message returned stating that the arguments are not numerical.

I hope you people can help me! Thanks a lot in advance!

Best, Jannik

Comment: `stat_function(fun = dnorm, arg = list(mean = mean(mtcars$mpg), sd = sd(mtcars$mpg)))`

Comment: stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(mtcars$mpg), sd = sd(mtcars$mpg)))

Comment: @ManojKumar (a) comments belong in, well, _Comments_ and (b) lookup "r function parameter partial matching" before deciding to do said commenting on working code.

Comment: This link gives better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688082/ggplot2-overlay-histogram-with-density-curve?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your curve and histograms are on different y scales and you didn't check the help page on `stat_function`, otherwise you'd've put the arguments in a `list` as it clearly shows in the example. You also aren't doing the `aes` right in your initial `ggplot` call. I sincerely suggest hitting up more tutorials and books (or at a minimum the help pages) vs learn ggplot piecemeal on SO.

Once you fix the `stat_function` arg problem and the ``` ggplot``aes ``` issue, you need to tackle the y axis scale difference. To do that, you'll need to switch the y for the histogram to use the density from the underlying `stat_bin` calculated data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg))
gg <- gg + geom_histogram(binwidth=2, colour="black", 
                          aes(y=..density.., fill=..count..))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient("Count", low="#DCDCDC", high="#7C7C7C")
gg <- gg + stat_function(fun=dnorm,
                         color="red",
                         args=list(mean=mean(mtcars$mpg), 
                                  sd=sd(mtcars$mpg)))

gg
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have the red curve extend to y=0?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work when the plot is faceted amongst multiple factors?

Comment: To extend to y=0, u can tweak the x-scale to the suitable value. 

`gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 40))`