# Plot normal distribution into existing plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution

I have this ggplot

```
ggplot(data = ph, aes(x = index1)) + geom_density()
```

and I would like to add a normal distribution with the same mean `(= 2.71)` and standard Deviation `(= 0.61)`.

I created the normal distribution with:

```
nd1 <- rnorm(n = 100000, mean = 2.71), sd = 0.61)
nd1plot <- qplot(nd1, geom = "density") + theme_classic() +  ggtitle("Normalverteilung")
```

But now I don't know how to add it to my existing plot. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: please use SO formatting and provide data example

Comment: I'm sorry... I didn't know how this worked out...

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29182589/2461552) might get you started.

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` has [stat_function()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/stat_function.html) for this kind of thing, but my solution takes a more manual approach in the name of clarity. You didn't provide an example of your data, but you should be able to replace `mtcars$mpg` with whatever column or vector you want.

```
library(tidyverse) # Gives us ggplot2 and lots of other goodies

# Choose your variable of interest
dta <- mtcars$mpg %>%
  as_tibble() # USing a tibble instead of a dataframe makes the data more predictable

# Generate normal data based on dta
norm_data <-
  rnorm(
    n = length(dta),
    mean = mean(dta$value),
    sd = sd(dta$value)
  )

# Create the plot
ggplot(dta, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_density(aes(norm_data), color = "darkgray", linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_classic()
```