# Overlay "normal distribution" on a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a histogram and I was hoping someone had some code so I could overlay a "normal" distribution so it is clear how my data deviates from that.
This is the code that I have rn:

```
  ggplot(examopg2, aes(x= ideology))+ 
  geom_bar()+ 
  labs(title = "Ideologi", x='Ideologi')+
  theme_classic()
```

The picture attached is roughly what I am looking for, thank y'all:)

[image]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: No picture is attached

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339178/overlay-normal-curve-to-histogram-in-ggplot2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967664/ggplot2-histogram-with-normal-curve helps to answer your question