# Overlaying histogram and density estimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, kernel-density

In psychometrics, you might have discrete measurements (e.g. on a scale from 1 to 4), but still assume that those measurements represent an underlying continuous process.

I am trying to produce a plot that depicts these discrete measurements and the underlying distribution.

So far I haven't managed to get what I produced. The best I have come up so far is trying to overlay the density plot on a histogram.
But there is a mismatch between the scale of the histogram densities and the scale of the density line:

```r
library(ggplot2)

var1  <- c(rep(1, times = 50),
           rep(2, times = 60),
           rep(3, times = 40),
           rep(4, times = 30))

df <- as.data.frame(var1)

ggplot(df, aes(x=var1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=..density..),stat = 'density') +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

My understanding is that I am looking at two different density functions:

- on the histogram, I oversample some parts of the distribution and undersample others, which produces "distorted" density estimates compared to
- the density line, where the density estimate is computed the whole (continuous) range of values on my interval.

... is there a way to get both functions to the same scale (or if not, maybe someone has a clue why it makes no statistical sense to try and do that).

Thanks!

Comment: the trick is to use `stat(density)` as y in `geom_histogram`, as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54700242/7941188

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick responses! I have another piece of work at hand right now, I will come back to this later.

Comment: I am still not getting the result I am looking for with this.
I am trying to produce a plot where the "tip" of the histogram is at the same height as the "tip" of the density curve.
Maybe you can share a reprex to see if we are really talking about the same thing?

Comment: to get the tip of the density curve at a desired point may not be straight forward - it is very much a matter of the smoothing parameter. (I think it is something like `bw = ...`) within the geom_density call