# geom_density NOT displaying over geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a density curve over histogram using ggplot but to no avail. **dlist** is a vector with numeric values.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=dlist), bins = 30, fill = "#B3E4F7") +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(dlist)),
             color="#D2091F", linetype="dashed",size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688082/overlay-histogram-with-density-curve>

Comment: Could you please add the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `y` to `..density..`. For example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(dlist), aes(x=dlist, y = ..density..)) +
        geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill = "#B3E4F7") +
        geom_density() +
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(dlist)),
                   color="#D2091F", linetype="dashed",size=1)
```

A reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = ..density..)) +
        geom_histogram(bins = 30,  fill = "#B3E4F7") +
        geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: dlist is a vector not a dataframe and therefore your code does not relate to my example.

Comment: @user9532692 this is just a reproducible example since you have not provided reproducible data (which is strongly recommended). This answer means that your problem should be solved by just specifying `y = ..density..` in your `aes`

Comment: @user9532692 see the updated code (the beginning of my answer) and let me know if it works for you. If not, please share some reproducible data by using `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

The geom_desntity has no data. Put the data in the ggplot() or in all functions.

```
ggplot(aes(x=dlist)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill = "#B3E4F7") +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(dlist)),color="#D2091F", linetype="dashed",size=1)
```

However, if you want to compare both, you may want to plot the histogram with a density stat:

```
ggplot(aes(x=dlist)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 30, fill = "#B3E4F7") +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(dlist)),color="#D2091F", linetype="dashed",size=1)
```

If you have a numeric vector `dlist`, you can create a data.frame before ggplot as follows:

```
dlist <- rnorm(1000)
tibble(dlist = dlist) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=dlist)) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 30, fill = "#B3E4F7") +
      geom_density() +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(dlist)),
                 color="#D2091F", linetype="dashed",size=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I get the following error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: Well, ggplot expect a data.frame. If you have a vector dlist, you can create one as follows: tibble(dlist = dlist) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=dlist)) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),bins = 30, fill = "#B3E4F7") +
      geom_density() +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(dlist)),
                 color="#D2091F", linetype="dashed",size=1)