# Fail to add normal density plot in histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below histogram using ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = .data[['x']])) +
stat_function(fun = function(x) dnorm(x, 0, sd(x))) +
geom_histogram(color = 'red', binwidth = 0.3) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, NA))
```

However, this plot fails to add normal density plot. Could you please help to bring normal probability plot along with the histogram?

Additionally, I also see that the bin is hitting floor as well as ceiling of the plot margin. I want to only fix the floor but keep the ceiling flexible. I tried with `expand = c(0, NA)` but looks like it is not working properly.

Comment: Possible dup: [Overlay histogram with density curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688082/overlay-histogram-with-density-curve)

Answer (score 1):

Your density is not appearing because the y-scale of your histogram is in counts. To overlay the density plot over the histogram, you will have to change the y axis to density. You can do so by adding the following:

```r
geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density), color = 'red', binwidth = 0.3) +
geom_density()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your y axis is plotting counts, not density values. Use `stat = 'density'` in `geom_histogram` to have a density.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = 'density', fill = 'red', colour = 'red') +
  stat_function(
    fun = dnorm,
    args = list(sd = sd(dat$x)),
    linewidth = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, NA))
#> Warning in geom_histogram(stat = "density", fill = "red", colour = "red"):
#> Ignoring unknown parameters: `binwidth`, `bins`, and `pad`
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Also, in the question's code `sd(x)` is computed in the anonymous function called by `stat_function`. The right way is below.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = 'density', fill = 'red', colour = 'red') +
  stat_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x, sd = sd(dat$x)), linewidth = 1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, NA))
```

Comment: In my case, the column name on which histogram will be drawn is variable. So I tried with `stat_function(fun = \(x) dnorm(x, sd = sd(.data$x)), linewidth = 1.5)` but this generates error. Is there any way to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with your code.

1. As pointed out, your histogram is count, not density. You need to supply `..density..` argument to geom_histogram.
2. The stat_function() is behind the histogram plot, and hence overshadowed.
3. You used rnorm(1000), which simulates values from a normal distribution meaning that mean must be 0 and the standard deviation 1 in the stat_function().

You also need to make sure the method you want to use for the density plot. `geom_density` uses non-parametric method; the stat_function() uses parametric.

The edited code would be:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), color = 'red', fill = 'white', binwidth = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(title = "Histogram with Density Plot", x = "Values", y = "Frequency") +
  theme_minimal()+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dnorm(x, 0, sd(x)))+ #your specification
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1), color = 'blue') #normal distribution
```

[image]